# Property is in intellisense, but still doesn't compile

Tags: linq-to-sql

I renamed one field in the database and added another. Then I removed the table from the DBML file, and re-added it. The I went to access the renamed property. The field shows up in intellisense, but will not compile, throwing a "no definition" error. I removed the project, reset the references, erased all the dlls, rebooted the machine, and nothing seems to work, it is still looking at the previous version of the DBML, except for intellisense.

Anyone seen something like this before, I suspect not, but I'd thought I'd ask anyway.

Here's some more info:

The old field name was "Revenue"
The new name is "RevenueUSD"

If I write "RevenueUSD" and right-click and "go to definition" I go right to the declaration, but the thing doesn't compile.

If I write "Revenue" and right-click and "go to definition" I can't go right to the declaration, but the thing does compile.

Whiskey Tango Foxtrot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the fact that the assembly name for my DBML project didn't match the project name. I brought those two things into algnment, and now Bob's my uncle.

Weird.